# UML Sequence Diagrams in RAD

Tags: rad, uml

I am trying to create several sequence diagrams in RAD, and I have two questions:

1. When I create a synchronous message, it automatically creates the dotted line, but I also need it to generate a < < return > > tag above the return message. I've tried looking in Preferences, and online there is almost no information for changing the settings for sequence diagrams in RAD.
2. Is there a way to convert these diagrams into .jpg format? They are currently .dnx files, and I would lose a large amount of detail if I had to simply take screenshots of these files.

If anyone has any familiarity with this, I appreciate any help you can give.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The image export is possible if you click on the diagram background and select Export as Image. Concerning return I don't remember but if you click on the message and open the message contextual menu you should be able to find out.
Good luck